# shasum for npm releases?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install node.js on Windows 7 without admin privileges.  I found instructions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/6tsV6ZA9RC4) which suggested downloading [node.exe](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/) and the [npm.zip](http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/).  In the directory for node.exe, there is a reassuring [SHASHUMS.txt](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS.txt) file, but not so for the npm.zip directory.  Are shasums available for the npm distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else worries about downloading npm.zip without checking the download's shasum, I thought I would post what I eventually did.  It turns out that the website for nodejs & npm also supports access over https, which means that if you change the URL for the npm.zip direcory to [this](https://nodejs.org/dist/npm/), then you can be assured that you have connected to the correct machine and downloaded what was there.  After some more thought, I concluded that a shasum file won't provide further assurance, since it only assures you that the creator of the shasum file trusted the npm.zip file, and if someone can mess with one, they can mess with the other (since in this case both would be on the same machine).

In this light, I am not sure what the point is of the SHASUMS.txt file in the "latest" directory (for node.exe), and it seems inconsistent that there is one there but not for the npm directory, but at least both node.exe and npm.zip can be safely downloaded over https.

Comment: often hashes are offered as a way to ensure the download completed without errors. You need cryptographic signatures to verify the origin of the file, though